# Enable-PSSession without credentials in hyper-v vm

Tags: powershell, remote-access, powershell-remoting

I want to access the Hyper-V VM without user credentials(without user name and password). Is there any way or PowerShell script or command to achieve this?

Comment: specify your goal not the task you want to achieve. you have to provide credentials for remote powershell sessions (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/powershell-direct).

Comment: Thanks Gurentdher Schmitz, But I am able to access remote machine with host PowerShell.  My question is to access remote machine without user credentials, SO that we can troubleshoot without troubling client every time asking for credentials.

Answer (score 1):

The credential-parameter is not mandatory. If you don't use it, the pssession will be created with your current user. If this user has the permission to access the remote server, the credentials aren't needed.

If you need an other user for the pssession, you need credentials. However you can create a credential object (`$cred = Get-Credential`) to store the credentials for longer powershell sessions where you need them repeatedly.

Comment: I am already login using Get-Credential, but i don't want credentials.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use a parameter `-Authentication NegotiateWithImplicitCredentials`.

Comment: Thank you montonero, please suggest if this is a right command or not 
Enter-PSSession -VMName 16core -Authentication NegotiateWithImplicitCredentials

Comment: It should be. Sorry, I haven't tried it with a connection to Hyper-V but it's worked with connection to host.